# Appropriate metric to monitor incoming load to a webjob in appservice

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-app-service-plans, azure-appservice

I have a webjob on an app service and there are scheduled times in a month where it receives peak load (not in terms of direct calls).

The webjob reads a ServiceBus Topic and processes messages concurrently `(MaxConcurrentThreads - 20)`. Incase of increased load, there are millions of messages in the SB topic to be processed `(usually the count is < 50 msgs/second, but on high load it reaches upto ~3M msgs/hour)`.

I analyzed couple of metric for autoscaling my webjob on such load and it seems `memory working set` (not avg) is a good measure of auto scaling apart from the regular CPU% (which in this case doesn't increase that drastically).

Any other suggestions on a useful metric that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

- You can try the "Diagnose and solve problems"

[image]

- Search "Webjob"

[image]

and see if that helps.